# jQuery Animation Trouble

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

There's a demo over [here](http://www.coralspringshigh.org/demo/) , and here's my current jQuery is

```
var height1 = $('.spotlight:nth-child(1)').height();
var height2 = $('.spotlight:nth-child(2)').height();

$('.spotlight').each(function() {
    var spot = $( this ),
        caption = $("<div class='caption'></div>").appendTo(spot);

    caption.load( spot.data('who') + '.html' );
    spot.hover(function() {
    caption.clearQueue().animate({ top :  '-=100px' }, 150)
    }, function () {
      caption.clearQueue().animate({ top : '+=100px' }, 150)
    });
});

$('.spotlight:nth-child(1) .caption').css('top', height1 + 'px');
$('.spotlight:nth-child(2) .caption').css('top', height2 + 'px');
```

And it all works fine and dandy, but there's the annoying animation loop if you keep going over it. I tried using .clearQueue() and .stop() but they come with bugs of their own ( if you move fast it goes too low or too high ) Anyway around this?

Comment: What do you mean about "animation loop"? In any case, not sure about that, but I did notice that if I move the mouse quickly between the two divs, the slideout text eventually stops sliding out. I think this is because you're using "-/+=100", and when the mouse triggers the other event before the first one is over, it screws up the "top" math and shifts the text further down.

Comment: @Val: the blue bg does have the hover.. @ilia: That is exactly what is happening, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: ok yes my bad :) `.stop(true, true)` could be the answer or try and reset the position of top to its default b4 `.animate()` and remove `clearQueue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `stop(false,true)` instead of `clearQueue()` ?

problem is that the clearQueue remove not run items (but you should not have some), and the `top` property is the top value of the current animation.

stop(false,true) will not clear the queue but jump to the animation end. Then top will be OK

Answer (score 0):

Perhap you should be using the .animate function instead.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I have a follow-up question to Val's...where can I get some?

Comment: lol - 3 hours sleep over the last 2 days...my bad I didn't read the code properly! ha-ha. I'm high on lack of sleep...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue could be that the animation is defined as a delta (-=100px). If this animation gets activated multiple times, it will continue to crawl up your div. I understand that you are trying to prevent the animation from being activated multiple times. I was able to recode using absolute positions. I am not seeing issues. Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/waDVX/

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="spotlight" data-who="staff"> 
    <div class="caption">
        <h1>Lipsum</h1>
        <p> There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
    </div>      
</div> 

<div class="spotlight" data-who="student"> 
    <div class="caption">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>testtestt estte stte sttest testte sttesttestt esttestte sttest</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.spotlight {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:270px;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;
    height:240px;
    background:#008ad0;
}
.caption {
   position:relative;
   opacity: 0.8;
   padding:10px;
   background:#000;
   color:#fff;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.spotlight').each(function() {
        var spot = $(this);
        var spotHeight = spot.outerHeight();
        var caption = $(".caption", spot);
        var height = caption.outerHeight();
        var top2 = spotHeight - height;
        var top1 = spotHeight;
        caption.css({top:top1});
        spot.hover(function() {
            caption.stop().animate({ top:top2 }, 150);
        }, function() {
            caption.stop().animate({top:top1}, 150);
        });
    });

});
```

Note: I removed the AJAX loading of the captions for simplicity.